# Issue installing R package from local tar.gz file - embedded null in string error

Tags: r, install.packages

I am encountering an issue while attempting to install an `R` package, `alineR_1.1.4.tar.gz`, from a local `tar.gz` file using the `install.packages` function. The package is deprecated and no longer available on `CRAN`. My goal is to modify certain parts of the package to better suit my needs.

Here's the code I'm using to install the modified package:

```
install.packages("~/Desktop/.../alineR_1.1.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

The package modification process involves unzipping the package, making the necessary changes to specific files, and then re-zipping the package. However, when I attempt to reinstall the modified package, I encounter the following error:

```
Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)]) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\0\0\0\00nnW\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\0 \0alineR/UT\r\0\a\xddlSe\xddlSe5\x85Seux\v\0\001\004\xf5\001\0\0\004\024\0\0\0PK\003\004\024\0\b\0\b\00nnW\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\024\001\0\0\021\0 \0_'
```

Accompanied by the following warning:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/.../alineR_1.1.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

It's worth noting that the error persists even if I only unzip and re-zip the package without making any changes to the files.

Comment: What commands exactly are you running to do the zipping/unzipping? What are you changing in the package? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick The error occurs regardless of whether I change anything within the package or not. On macOS, I double-click the file to decompress it and then right-click the folder and select "Compress" to compress it again. Finally, I change the file type from `.zip` to `.tar.gz`.

Comment: `.zip` is not the same as `.tar.gz`. Those are two different, incompatible compression types. To create a `.tar.gz` file you need to run something like `tar -czvf alineR_1.1.4.tar.gz folder/` at the terminal

Comment: @MrFlick if you add it as an answer, I will accept it as the correct one